# How to get the name of a button that I want to drag on a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

[image: Input panel and out put panel]

I am new to C# & WinForm, I searched the internet but count not find the the solution I was looking for. It will be very good if someone please help me.

Here is my problem-

---

I have created a Form like the above image. There are 3 panels-

1. Input Panel (It actually holds some Buttons)
2. To Drag Panel (User will  drag Button from "Input panel" to this panel)
3. Output Panel (It will tell the name of the Button from the "To Drag Panel")

   - If user Drag multiple Button then the Output Panel also show multiple names.

Comment: you can get the dragged button name by .Name property.  **string draggedName = draggedButton.Name;**

Comment: This is true if and only if the Name __property__ is what he wants. some folks seek the name of the __variable__ which may be something different.. To get at that one has to use reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
private void UpdateLabel()
{
    label1.Text = "";
    foreach (Control c in DragPanel.Controls)   //Going through all controls in the panel
    {
        if (c.GetType().Name == "Button")        // Checking whether the control is a Button
            label1.Text += Environment.NewLine+ ((Button)c).Text;     //Updating the label
    }
}
```

Call the function `UpdateLabel()` when a button has been dragged to the panel.

**Explanation:**

This code will select all controls in DragPanel, and if it is a Button, it will take the value of `Text` property and append to the label in a new line.

**EDIT:**

You can replace `Button` with the control name you want (ex: `TextBox`).

```
foreach (Control c in DragPanel.Controls)   
{
    if (c.GetType().Name == "TextBox")     
    {
          label1.Text += Environment.NewLine + ((TextBox)c).Text;     
    }
}
```

If you want to get all controls in the panel, then you can do:

```
foreach (Control c in DragPanel.Controls) 
{
      label1.Text += Environment.NewLine + c.Text;  
}
```

Comment: This worked.
But if I want to get other Control than Button, should I have to replace "Button" with <ControlName> (ex. TextBox) ??

Comment: @RupamBhaduri: Yes, of course. You can use any control name there. If you want to list all controls, then you can remove the if statement. I will update my answer.

Comment: Please give a example.
Then will the text
label1.Text += Environment.NewLine+ ((Button)c).Text    work ?
Because there is ((Button)c).Text

Answer (score -1):

```
var dragged = dragPanel.Controls
                       .OfType<typeof(Button)>()
                       .Select(button => button.Text);
```

Comment: @NikolayKostov: what there is needed to explain? this code selects all the buttons (text), then you can output it as you want....

Comment: This code did not work as I was unable to find the uses of this code.
But thanks for giving answer.